# List of applications of the Deformation theory of Galois Representations in contexts other that $R=T$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, deformation-theory, galois-representations, iwasawa-theory

The Deformation theory of Galois representations developed by Mazur has been extensively used in proving that Galois representations with special properties are modular/automorphic through the application of $R=T$ theorems. It has also been used in proving geometric lifting theorems of residual Galois representations (in Serre's conjecture).

Here are four applications of Deformation theory of Galois representations in other contexts that I am aware of:

1. Its Iwasawa theoretic applications in the papers of Ralph Greenberg.
2. Its use in a theorem of Bockle and Khare which gives an alternate proof of de Jong's conjecture which is a conjecture about the finiteness of certain representations of arithmetic fundamental groups of nice curves over a finite field [BK](http://vp5qw4uf5x.search.serialssolutions.com/?sid=AMS%3AMathSciNet&atitle=Mod%20%24l%24%20representations%20of%20arithmetic%20fundamental%20groups%20%20II%20%20A%20conjecture%20of%20A%20%20J%20%20de%20Jong&aufirst=Gebhard&auinit1=G&aulast=B%C3%B6ckle&date=2006&epage=294&genre=article&issn=0010-437X&issue=2&pages=271-294&spage=271&stitle=Compos.%20Math.&title=Compositio%20Mathematica&volume=142&id=doi:10.1112%2FS0010437X05002022). Also related is their proof of Serre's conjecture in the function field case.
3. Ohtani and Blondeau construct certain special Galois extensions over $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{\infty}})$.
4. Ochai on deformations of Euler systems.

Are there any other applications missing from this list?